# Different format of bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I would like the item in my bibliography to be format like this:
[image: Author and year a side, then the entire references]

How can I achive this outcome?

I'm using \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} and any package for the bibliography: that is

```
\section*{Bibliography}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Bibliography}
\textsc{Adler 1967} = \textsc{A. Adler}, \emph{Suidae Lexicon}, Vol. 2, Teubner, Stuttgart 1967.
```

Comment: Please add some more information: which documentclass do you use, can you show us the bib entrys for the bib file, do you compile with pdflatex, do you use biblatex and biber oder bibtex, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This structure for the bibliography is straightforward to achieve with [Bibulous](http://nzhagen.github.io/bibulous/), as long as the citation key in the text is the same as the bibliography label. Using the OOP's setup, we can create a `.bib` database file

```
@PREAMBLE{"\setlength{\labelwidth}{30mm}"}
@PREAMBLE{"\setlength{\itemindent}{0mm}"}
@PREAMBLE{"\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}"}
@BOOK{Perrotta1935,
  author = {G. Perrotta},
  title = {Saffo e Pindaro},
  address = {Bari},
  year = 1935}
@BOOK{Cumont1913,
  author = {Fr. Cumont},
  title = {Les myst{\`e}res de Mithra},
  address = {Bruxelles},
  year = 1913}
@TRANSLATEDBOOK{Havelock1973,
  author = {Eric A. Havelock},
  title = {Cultura orale e civilt{\`a} della scrittura},
  address = {Roma-Bari},
  year = 1973}
@ARTICLE{Prato1993,
  author = {C. Prato},
  title = {Note al testo di Giuliano Imperatore},
  journal = {Rudiae},
  volume = 5,
  year = 1993,
  pages = {117--121}}
```

The PREAMBLE lines at the top are what we can use to create the columnated structure that the OOP is looking for. The "translatedbook" entry type is used to handle the different style used for a translated book. Next, we can create a style template file of the form

```
TEMPLATES:
article = \textsc{<au>}, \enquote{<title>}, \textit{<journal>} <volume>, <year>, [pp.~<startpage>--<endpage>|p.~<startpage>|].
book = \textsc{<au>}, \textit{<title>}, <address> <year>.
translatedbook = \textsc{<au>}, \textit{<title>}, trad.\ it.\ <address> <year>.

SPECIAL-TEMPLATES:
authorlist = <author.to_namelist()>
editorlist = <editor.to_namelist()>
au = <authorlist.format_authorlist()>
ed = <editorlist.format_editorlist()>
authorlabel = [<authorlist.0.prefix>|<authorlist.0.last>|]
editorlabel = [<editorlist.0.prefix>|<editorlist.0.last>|]
sortkey = [\textsc{<authorlabel>} <year>|\textsc{<editorlabel>} <year>|]
citelabel = <sortkey>
```

The `citelabel` variable here is what Bibulous uses for the itemlabel in the bibliography list, and the template instructs that it should use the author's last name in small caps, followed by a space, and then the year, as the item label. This is also what will appear at the location of the citation within the text.

Finally, we can compile the results using the following `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paper=letterpaper,text={4in,9in},centering]{geometry}
\makeatletter
   \renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{#1}    %% Get rid of square brackets around bibliography labels.
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{example}
\bibliography{example}
\end{document}
```

to give the formatted bibliography shown below

[image]